# Turning data populated by formula into 'solid' data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that includes data pulled together from other sheets using VLOOKUP and other formulas. I want to copy columns directly into another sheet for someone else to use and manipulate, but I can't copy the sheet as the formulas no longer work and all boxes are filled with `#NA`.

Is it possible to somehow turn the data shown (but where a formula lies underneath) into actual data (so that the cell contains only the number shown, not a formula)?

Comment: Can you not use copy-and-paste-values?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Either Copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then, having selected your destination, Edit > Paste special > Paste **values** only, or when pasting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.